# CKFinder Not Displaying Thumbnails Issue

Tags: php, ckeditor, ckfinder

Thumbnails not showing in ckfinder.
There is an "unknown error" message.
When I click on the picture, the picture appears fine in ckeditor.
But it doesn't show thumbnails Error.
No matter what I did I couldn't solve my problem.
I would be glad if you help me.

[image: Browser Error]

Folder layout:
[image: Folder layout]

[image: CKFinder Modal]

config.php

```
$config = array();

$config['authentication'] = function () {
    return true;
};

$config['licenseName'] = '';
$config['licenseKey']  = '';

$config['privateDir'] = array(
    'backend' => 'default',
    'tags'   => '.ckfinder/tags',
    'logs'   => '.ckfinder/logs',
    'cache'  => '.ckfinder/cache',
    'thumbs' => '.ckfinder/cache/thumbs',
);

$config['images'] = array(
    'maxWidth'  => 1600,
    'maxHeight' => 1200,
    'quality'   => 80,
    'sizes' => array(
        'small'  => array('width' => 480, 'height' => 320, 'quality' => 80),
        'medium' => array('width' => 600, 'height' => 480, 'quality' => 80),
        'large'  => array('width' => 800, 'height' => 600, 'quality' => 80)
    )
);

$config['backends'][] = array(
    'name'         => 'default',
    'adapter'      => 'local',
    'baseUrl'      => '/',
    'root'         => '/var/www/******/public_html/www/eshop/../../*******/', // Can be used to explicitly set the CKFinder user files directory.
    'chmodFiles'   => 0777,
    'chmodFolders' => 0755,
    'filesystemEncoding' => 'UTF-8',
);

$config['defaultResourceTypes'] = '';
 
$config['resourceTypes'][] = array(
    'name'              => 'Images',
    'directory'         => 'images',
    'maxSize'           => 0,
    'allowedExtensions' => 'bmp,gif,jpeg,jpg,png',
    'deniedExtensions'  => '',
    'backend'           => 'default'
);

....
```

Comment: This looks like a folder permission issue. Could you please try enabling debug mode and see what is the exact error? https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/ckfinder3-php/debugging.html#debugging_debugging

Comment: Thank you. I solved my problem because of you :)

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the my problem.
Not permission in .ckfinder/*
chmod 775 :)